# turn 0.05 into 5% jquery or javascript

Tags: jquery, html, percentage

Hi I am wondering how do I turn 0.05 or any 0.xx into a percentage for example
if 0.1 it should be 10% if 0.04 its 4%

it should also round up, I know how to take the a from b and get the percentage this way, but am not sure how to get it to work. I have tried to use `parseFloat` but that has not worked, can anyone suggest the way to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such a simple manipulation, you do not need jQuery at all.

```
Number.prototype.percent = function() {
    // Round number up: Math.ceil
    // Round number: Math.round
    // Round number down: Math.floor
    return Math.ceil(this*100) + "%";
}
```

By using this function, you modify `Number` prototype. Then, you can use it everywhere, like this :

```
console.log((0.04).percent()); // 4%
console.log((1).percent());    // 100%
var number = 0.1;
console.log(number.percent()); // 10%
```

Comment: You may want to use `Math.ceil()` instead, as it always rounds UP.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by 100 and then concat the `%`.

`(num * 100).toFixed(2) + '%'`

Comment: Make sure to round the multiplication result.

Comment: @DCoder It depends on the op's requirement.

Comment: `console.log(0.07 * 100) => 7.000000000000001`.

Answer (score 0):

Try folowing

```
parseInt(num*100)+"%"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var decimal2percent = function (num) {
    return parseInt(parseFloat(num) * 100).toString() + "%";
};
```